# How to control width of rectangular selection in Emacs 25?

Tags: rectangle

There is a cool new feature in Emacs 25: visual support for rectangular
selection. However, I would like to set its width to one pixel when it's
“logical” width is zero columns of text. By default it's a bit too bold. Is
it possible?

Also, it would be cool if it didn't “shift” text on the right side of the
selection when its width is zero.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as of now there is no (non-hacking) way to achieve what you want. Looking at [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/rect.el#n808) an overlay with a space is added when the rectangle is of zero width.

Comment: Too bad, I've sent a bug report: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21386